# PHP 7 zend framework 1.12 and foreach using partials

Tags: php, zend-framework

We migrated our system with Zend Framework 1.11.9 to PHP 7. Making several adjustments between them updating Zend Framework 1.12.12 we manage to make it work.

However there is a problem with the following message

> “Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach ()”

in the next code

```
foreach ($this->list as $value){
$record->setAttribute(‘id’, $value[‘id’]);
…
$recordList->append($record);
}
```

In a call from a system view this fragment works.Where the warning does not return values in the loop, it is an implementation within a partials directory. That is, a view that has additional code for the user. The value of list is null.

**Does someone have a similar problem?**

Comment: Those forward ticks don't look right.  Is this verboten?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what `$this->list` is, or rather should be.  As if it is null, it's not iterable.  Perhaps the assignment of that is broken.